# Jest testing api creates own context node js

Tags: javascript, node.js, jestjs

I am testing with jest in node js.

my file index.js

```
const config = helper.config;
const _ = helper.module._;
```

it throws error.

```
helper is not defined.
```

here helper is global object.

my jest testing js

```
const assign = require('xxxxxx/index');

const body = {}

describe("forgotPassword()", () => {
    it("should return true", () => {
        //Testing a boolean
        expect(assign(body)).toBeTruthy();
        //Another way to test a boolean
        expect(assign(body)).toEqual(true);
    });
});
```

Is there any way ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found answer to this.

I wanted to run some files before running test.

add this to `package.json`

```
 "jest": {
    "setupFiles": ["./app.js"]
}
```

Add file in setupFiles. this file will run before testing starts.